# how to fix " java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 2 from CursorWindow."

Tags: android, sqlite

i recently learn to write a code in android using sqlite and i try to select data from sqlite but this error occur

ive tried some suggestion from the internet (stackoverflow question and other website) and read my book but it didnt solve my problem thank you

ive tried to change cursor syntax to cursor.getcolumname but it didnt solve it, ive tried to change sqlitedatabase.query , ive read suggestion from the internet but still didnt salve my problem

```
 public Penyakit getPenyakit1(String namaGejal){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = " SELECT  idPen FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE " + 
  namapen + " =\'" + namaGejal + "\'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    Penyakit penyakit = new Penyakit();
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        penyakit.set_idPenyakit(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
        cursor.close();
    }else{
        penyakit=null;
    }
    return penyakit;
}
  eror logcat
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 2 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:465)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
```

heres my variable in case you wondering

```
here my variable in case u wondering
     private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS ="tb_penyakit";
private static final String nomber="nomber";
private static final String namapen ="namapen";
private static final String idPen="idPen";
private static final String namaGej ="namaGej";
private static final String idGej="idGej";
```

i expected value of idPen selected from sqlite database

Comment: You're only getting one column in query `idPen` so use `cursor.getString(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks everyone , it solve with this code

```
  public Penyakit getPenyakit1(String namaGejal){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] colums = {nomber,namapen,idPen,namaGej,idGej};
    String selection = namapen + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(namaGejal)};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, colums, selection,
            selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    Penyakit penyakit = new Penyakit();
    if (null != cursor) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        penyakit.set_nomber(cursor.getInt(0));
        penyakit.set_namaPen(cursor.getString(1));
        penyakit.set_idPenyakit(cursor.getInt(2));
        penyakit.set_namGej(cursor.getString(3));
        penyakit.set_idGejala(cursor.getInt(4));

    }else{
        penyakit=null;
    }
    db.close();
    return penyakit;
}
```